# inserting datetime into sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, wxpython

inserting date time values into it's proper column yield this error

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\sad pROG\Order.py", line 30
(Order_ID, Cust_ID,Order_Price, Order_Date))
Warning: Out of range value for column 'Order_Date' at row 1
```

I've set the Order_Date as datetime

and here's the insert format

self.c.execute("insert into orders values (%s, %s, %s,%s)",
                       (Order_ID, Cust_ID,Order_Price, Order_Date))

pretty sure the last %s should be something else when inserting the aforementioned value....

now I also tried using the wx.DateTime.Now() method in the front end wen adding entries

```
def add_entry(self, event):
        """Add a new entry to the Order_Date ite"""
        # start out with blank, generic ItemEntry
        date =DateTime.Now()
        entry = o.OrderEntry("","",0.0,date)
        self.endiag = OrderDetail(self,entry)
        self.endiag.ShowModal()           



        self.ord.add_entry(entry.Order_ID,
                            entry.Cust_ID,
                            str(entry.Order_Price),
                            str(entry.Order_Date) )
```

aaand in the method above, I tried setting a variable for the date and it nets me this particular error stack

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\sad pROG\Order.py", line 30
(Order_ID, Cust_ID,Order_Price, Order_Date))
Warning: Data truncated for column 'Order_Date' at row 1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html:

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

We're not familiar with your program at all so debug and output Order_Date for yourself and see if it matches that expected format.  Also, make sure your field in MySQL is datetime, and not timestamp, int, date, etc.

**Edit:**

If you look at the Python documentation for datetime (docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), you'll see you're given seconds since the epoch as a floating point value (that's what I skimmed and read at least). Either convert your Python datetime value or change your MySQL field type.

Comment: hmmmm if it's the case what's the proper format I can use in my sql statement...... given that %s is not working and I set the entry.Order_Date as a string beforehand?

Comment: Just because you cast something to a string doesn't mean it'll automagically become the string in the format you want.
Also, just because something is called `datetime` both in Python and MySQL doesn't mean they're the same format.  Just like chips in America means potato chips and in England means french fries.
If you look at the Python documentation for datetime (http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), you'll see you're given seconds since the epoch (that's what I skimmed and read).  Either convert your Python datetime value or change your MySQL field type.

Comment: Don't set entry.order_date to a string.  It's a bad habit to get into.  There has to be another answer.  I just don't know what it is because I work with neither MySQL nor python.

Comment: Okay so I didn't set it into a string.. thing is I'm passing it as a variable of sorts from the front end to the back end... I dunno how to properly cast it in the insert sql statement hence the data truncated error

Comment: usng the now() function brings me the datetime in MM-DD-YYY HH:MM:SS format... need a way to cast that properly in the sql statement......